# How to take drop down menu value to views.py in django?

Tags: django, django-views

I am using drop down menu.I want to take selected option on views.py but as I am passing id as value and when use `request.POST.get("operator")` to get selected item's name it's displaying id instead of name
please check below code on template and when I take value=operator's name it gives me operator name but I want id also for passing to another function.
should I take both and splits them , please suggest solution

```
  <select  class="form-control" id="sel1" name="oprator"  data-live-search="true" onchange="getOprInfo(this.value)" >
     <option value="  ">Select Operator</option>
          {%for operator in operators%}
                <option value="{{operator.id}}">{{operator}}</option>
           {%endfor%}
   </select>
```

code on models.py

```
class Recharge_Operators(models.Model):
recharge_type = (
    ('Prepaid', 'Prepaid'),
    ('PostPaid', 'PostPaid'),
)
bill_gen = (
    ('Y', 'Yes'),
    ('N', 'No'),
)
operators_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
type = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=recharge_type)
service_id = models.ForeignKey(Service,related_name='op_service_id')
verification_url = models.TextField()
payment_url = models.TextField()
status_url = models.TextField()
bill_generate = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=bill_gen)
min_value = models.CharField(max_length=20)
max_value = models.CharField(max_length=20)
interval = models.CharField(max_length=10)
comment = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField()

def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ for Python 2
    return self.operators_name
```

Comment: can you show the code for the operator model  ?

Comment: above is the  operator model code

Comment: it looks fine. can you inspect the html from browser and check if the value for every option is generated properly ?

Comment: values are generating properly as 1, 2,3....but i want its name for example first operator is Test

Comment: on next page i am not able to show selected name for ex. Test it displays id

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if this is what you want but it seems like you want the operators name as  option value then you should be using name instead of id in your template like this:

```
<option value="{{operator.operators_name}}">{{operator}}</option>
```

because you have already defined:

```
def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ for Python 2
    return self.operators_name
```

so simply printing the model object also prints the operator name, so you can also do:

```
 <option value="{{operator}}">{{operator}}</option>
```

Or by default HTML options are assigned the same value as the label if you do not give a value attribute so you can also do:

```
 <option>{{operator}}</option>
```

Comment: but i also want id because i am passing that id to another function..in short i want both id and item name..